# C check array content at compile time

Tags: c, arrays, compile-time

I have an enum and an array of a structure. The first field in the structure is of the enum type. Now I want to check at compile time, if the value in the first field of the first array element is the same as the first value of the enum type. Same with the second element and so on...

Basically like this:

```
typedef enum {
   A = 0,
   B,
   C
} enumerator1;

typedef struct {
   enumerator1   a;
   unsigned char foo;
   unsigned char bar;
} structure1;

const structure1 array1[3] =
{
   {A, 1, 1},   //This element should contain A
   {C, 1, 1},   //This element should contain B
   {B, 1, 1}    //This element should contain C
};
```

In the example above, B and C are swapped and I would like to catch this at compile time.
What I am looking for is something like this:

```
#if array1[0].a != A
#error
#endif
```

But that's not working, compiler says "token "[" is not valid in preprocessor expressions".
I also tried it with something like this:

```
typedef unsigned char Check[(array1[0].a != A) ? 1 : -1];
```

But with the same result.
How, if possible, can I implement such a check?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a very typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): You show us a solution you have problem with, but you don't tell us the actual problem you're trying to solve. *Why* do you need to check the contents of the array at compile-time? What is your use-case for this?

Comment: The enumeration is defined inside a global header and is quite big actually. The array is defined in another module. Many developers work on this project and it happens that someone e.g. changes the enumeration, adding one object, or changing the order of elements without telling the developer of the module where the array is defined about it and so this could lead to errors but in the worst case you will not see the error immediately so I want to add this compile time check.
I know this is a problem that should better be solved on a project/configuration management level...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Arrays in C are conceptually a runtime thing. There's no portable way to force a comptime assertion on that.

That doesn't mean an optimizing compiler won't see into it.

If I do `if(!(array1[0].a == A)) abort();` and look at the disassembly, I can see that both gcc and clang are completely eliding this code when I compile with optimization on.

There is a GCC trick that allows you to turn this optimizer knowledge into a comptime assertion (or an ASAP assertion
as I call it).

```
#if __GNUC__ && !__clang__
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Walloc-size-larger-than=999999999L"
#endif

#if NDEBUG
enum { ndebug=1};
#else
enum { ndebug=0};
#endif

#include <assert.h>
#define ASAP_ASSERT(X)  \
        do{  \
            /*if possible, statically assert it even without the optimizer*/ \
            (void)(__builtin_constant_p(X) ? sizeof(int[(X)?1:-1]) : 0); \
            _Bool ASAP_ASSERT=(X); /*prevent double evaluation*/ \
            if(!ndebug){ \
                /*try to make the optimizer raise a -Walloc-size-larger-than=*/ \
                _Bool volatile ASAP_ASSERT__[(ASAP_ASSERT)?1:-1]; \
                ASAP_ASSERT__[0]=0; \
                (void)ASAP_ASSERT__; \
            } \
            assert(ASAP_ASSERT); /*if all static assert attempts fail, do it dynamically*/ \
        }while(0)

typedef enum {
   A = 0,
   B,
   C
} enumerator1;

typedef struct {
   enumerator1   a;
   unsigned char foo;
   unsigned char bar;
} structure1;

const structure1 array1[3] =
{
   {A, 1, 1},   //This element should contain A
   {C, 1, 1},   //This element should contain B
   {B, 1, 1}    //This element should contain C
};
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{

    ASAP_ASSERT(array1[0].a!=A); //will cause a comptime failure on gcc when compiled with at least -O1
}
```

The downsides are that it's GCC specific, has a small runtime cost (the volatile write, which you can turn off by setting ndebug to 1, but then you won't get the compile time failure) and I've had some false positives with it.